# Missing "Virtual Disk" service in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I can't start Windows Disk Management because of an error that "Disk Management cannot start Virtual Disk Service (VDS)". The proper solution to this is generally to make sure the "Virtual Disk" service is started using services.msc HOWEVER when I try to do this the Virtual Disk service simply isn't there! I've thoroughly checked both the standard and extended lists but there's nothing that even resembles it.

I've checked "Programs and Features" -> Windows Features to make sure I didn't uninstall it by mistake but there's nothing obvious there. Also sfc reports no problems. There is a vds.exe in C:\Windows\System32 .

How can this service be missing and more importantly how do I get it back (without a reformat)?

Comment: Maybe this could be of help: http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/79241-virtual-disk-manager.html. It suggests checking that the disk defragmenter isn't disabled.

Comment: I saw that but I'm pretty sure it's bogus advice. As far as I can tell "Disk Defragmenter" isn't a service nor can it be uninstalled or disabled globally (just per-disk). There is a program/module called "defrag.exe" but it just crashes so I'm guessing it depends on VDS, not the other way around.

Comment: Disk Defragmenter is the name of the standard Windows service, if that is not listed either then it is probably related to your problem.

Comment: Have you checked the System event logs in the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: I didn't find anything in the Event Log. Even a generic search for 'disk' didn't turn up any obviously relevant errors.

Comment: @James: "Disk Defragmenter" isn't in the services list either so I suppose it is at least related. Not sure if it's the chicken or the egg though.

Comment: Do you have Norton Antivirus installed by any chance?

Comment: No antivirus, just Spybot S&D. Turned off firewall, didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

With elevated privileges, open Command prompt and run `sfc.exe /scannow`.

Again, `vds.exe` is just the executable, it depends on `vdsldr.exe` (service loader) and corresponding DLLs (`vds_ps.dll`, `vdsbas.dll`, `vdsdyn.dll`, `vdsutil.dll`, `vdsvd.dll`). Check your system32 folder.

`vds.exe` size is 521KB here.

[image]

Comment: As stated in the question `sfc` reports no errors. I guess I can check those files by hand. I know vdsldr.exe is there, i'll check the others.

Comment: Got vds.exe (512kb), vdsldr.exe (22kb) and DLLs vds_ps (114kb), vdsbas (187kb). vdsdyn (569kb), vdsutil (182kb) and vdsvd (54kb)